# In python is "key not in container" allowed, or must we write "not (key in container)?"

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, contains, negation

In python, I know that it is permissible to write:

```
happy_bag = list()

if not (key in happy_bag):
    print(key, " ain't in da bag.")
```

But would it also be okay to write:

```
happy_bag = list()

if key not in happy_bag:
    print(key, " ain't in da bag.")
```

Also, the following is legal:

```
if key in happy_bag:
    print("Congratulations! you have a ", key, " in your bag!")
```

But is it alright if we add the word "is"?

```
if key is in happy_bag:
    print("Congratulations! you have a ", key, " in your bag!")
```

Comment: If there just were some interactive Python interpreter around to check that. ;-)

Comment: Title and content got out of sync. It seems like you answered the title already but asking a new question instead. Just a question though: What, if it were possible, would you expect `is in` to do?

Comment: @MSeifert I expect they're trying to make it read closer to English. They're probably not intending the `is` to act at the actual operator.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can't always get code to read perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly correct to write:

```
container = []
key = 1
if key not in container:
    print("Not found")
```

And it is even advised. From [PEP 8: Programming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

> Use **is not** operator rather than **not ... is**. While both expressions are functionally identical, the former is more readable and preferred.

regarding your second question `is in` is not a correct operator in python. The operator `is` is used to test reference identity:

```
a = []
b = []
c = a
assert(a == b) # good, the two lists compare equal as per list.__eq__
assert(a is b) # fails, the two names don't refer to the same object
assert(a is c) # good, c and a point to the same list
```